# Is it safe to swap cards with Magic Lantern on them between two identical Canon cameras?

Tags: canon, memory-card, canon-7d, magic-lantern

I have two similar cameras, both 7Ds. Both have Magic Lantern installed and both use their own CF card. Is it safe to borrow a card from the other camera when needed? Or should I uninstall ML from one card before inserting it to the other camera?

Comment: Are you using the exact same version of ML on both? The same firmware version in both 7Ds?

Comment: Yes, both cameras have downgraded to 2.0.3 and use same ML.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real way to "install" *Magic Lantern (ML)* to a camera. It always remains on the memory card that is used to boot the camera into ML when it is turned on. Put in a card without ML on it and that camera can not be booted with ML, it will use the Canon firmware already in the camera.

As long as the version of ML on your memory card is compatible with the firmware version installed in the camera there should be no issues.

Comment: Thank you! I know ML is just a file on the card. I wasn't sure about added boot command in camera.. that does it look for any ML files startup or does it look for same exact file that was used to add the bootflag.